# Connecting griddb in Fixed mode using mwcloud GridStore library in java

Tags: java, griddb

My grid db instance is running in FIXED mode. I am able to connect griddb using jdbc in java. Now, I am trying to use com.toshiba.mwcloud Gridstore library to connect with griddb. As the library has better functions to interact with griddb containers and to store data in time series. I am using 20001 port as I am able connect via jdbc using the same port. Below is code I am using to connect via Gridstore library.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws GSException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("notificationMember", "192.168.139.234:20001");

    props.setProperty("clusterName", "myCluster");
    props.setProperty("user", "admin");
    props.setProperty("password", "admin");

    GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance()
        .getGridStore(props);

    // working till here
    Collection<String, Student> students = store.putCollection("STUDENT", Student.class);
    
    Student student = students.createRow();


    Query<Student> query = people.query("select * where name = 'John'");
    RowSet<Student> rs = query.fetch(false);
    while (rs.hasNext()) {
        // Update the searched Row
        Person student1 = rs.next();
            System.out.println("Name: "+ student1.name +" Age: "+ student1.age);
    }
    System.out.println("endded connection");
}

static class Student  {

    @RowKey
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

I am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.common.GSStatementException: [10054:TXN_CLIENT_VERSION_NOT_ACCEPTABLE] (connectClientVersion=15, serverVersion=-9) (address=192.168.139.234:20001, partitionId=0)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.NodeConnection.executeStatementDirect(NodeConnection.java:528)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.NodeConnection.executeStatement(NodeConnection.java:345)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.NodeConnection.connect(NodeConnection.java:947)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.NodeConnectionPool.resolve(NodeConnectionPool.java:166)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.NodeResolver.updateConnectionAndClusterInfo(NodeResolver.java:680)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.NodeResolver.prepareConnectionAndClusterInfo(NodeResolver.java:565)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.NodeResolver.getPartitionCount(NodeResolver.java:241)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.GridStoreChannel$5.execute(GridStoreChannel.java:2277)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.GridStoreChannel.executeStatement(GridStoreChannel.java:1847)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.GridStoreChannel.executeResolver(GridStoreChannel.java:2084)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.GridStoreChannel.resolvePartitionId(GridStoreChannel.java:2274)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.SubnetGridStore.putContainer(SubnetGridStore.java:992)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.SubnetGridStore.putCollection(SubnetGridStore.java:1049)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.SubnetGridStore.putCollection(SubnetGridStore.java:797)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.subnet.SubnetGridStore.putCollection(SubnetGridStore.java:100)
at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.partitioned.PartStore.putCollection(PartStore.java:177)
at gridfs.GridStoreConnectionExample.main(GridStoreConnectionExample.java:31)
```

I am getting the error at line `Collection<String, Student> students = store.putCollection("STUDENT", Student.class)`

Not sure, what I am missing here.

gs_stat looks like below:

```
{
"checkpoint": {
    "backupOperation": 0,
    "duplicateLog": 0,
    "endTime": 1707936787683,
    "mode": "RECOVERY_CHECKPOINT",
    "normalCheckpointOperation": 0,
    "pendingPartition": 0,
    "periodicCheckpoint": "ACTIVE",
    "requestedCheckpointOperation": 0,
    "startTime": 1707936786930
},
"cluster": {
    "activeCount": 1,
    "applyRuleLimitTime": "2024-02-15T00:23:51.095+05:30",
    "autoGoal": "ACTIVE",
    "clusterName": "myCluster",
    "clusterRevisionId": "68961817-525f-491a-83df-b6e229bb7b36",
    "clusterRevisionNo": 6,
    "clusterStatus": "MASTER",
    "currentRule": "Initial",
    "designatedCount": 1,
    "loadBalancer": "ACTIVE",
    "master": {
        "address": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 10040
    },
    "nodeList": [
        {
            "address": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 10040
        }
    ],
    "nodeStatus": "ACTIVE",
    "notificationMode": "FIXED_LIST",
    "partitionStatus": "NORMAL",
    "startupTime": "2024-02-15T00:23:05.095+05:30",
    "syncCount": 2
},
"currentTime": "2024-02-15T00:23:35+05:30",
"performance": {
    "backgroundMinRate": 0.1,
    "backupCount": 0,
    "checkpointFileFlushCount": 128,
    "checkpointFileFlushTime": 31,
    "checkpointWrite": 0,
    "checkpointWriteCompressTime": 0,
    "checkpointWriteSize": 0,
    "checkpointWriteTime": 0,
    "currentTime": 1707936815881,
    "dataFileAllocateSize": 1245184,
    "dataFileSize": 1245184,
    "dataFileUsageRate": 0.8421052631578947,
    "expirationDetail": {
        "batchScanNum": 2000,
        "batchScanTotalNum": 0,
        "batchScanTotalTime": 0,
        "erasableExpiredTime": "",
        "estimatedBatchFree": 0,
        "estimatedErasableExpiredTime": "",
        "lastBatchFree": 0,
        "latestExpirationCheckTime": "Under measurement"
    },
    "logFileFlushCount": 256,
    "logFileFlushTime": 1134,
    "numBackground": 0,
    "numConnection": 1,
    "numNoExpireTxn": 0,
    "numSession": 0,
    "numTxn": 0,
    "ownerCount": 128,
    "peakProcessMemory": 69464064,
    "poolBufferMemory": 393216,
    "processMemory": 69464064,
    "sqlNumConnection": 1,
    "sqlStoreSwapRead": 0,
    "sqlStoreSwapReadSize": 0,
    "sqlStoreSwapReadTime": 0,
    "sqlStoreSwapWrite": 0,
    "sqlStoreSwapWriteSize": 0,
    "sqlStoreSwapWriteTime": 0,
    "storeCompressionMode": "NO_BLOCK_COMPRESSION",
    "storeDetail": {
        "batchFreeMapData": {
            "storeMemory": 0,
            "storeUse": 0,
            "swapRead": 0,
            "swapWrite": 0
        },
        "batchFreeRowData": {
            "storeMemory": 0,
            "storeUse": 0,
            "swapRead": 0,
            "swapWrite": 0
        },
        "mapData": {
            "storeMemory": 0,
            "storeUse": 393216,
            "swapRead": 0,
            "swapWrite": 0
        },
        "metaData": {
            "storeMemory": 393216,
            "storeUse": 393216,
            "swapRead": 6,
            "swapWrite": 0
        },
        "rowData": {
            "storeMemory": 0,
            "storeUse": 262144,
            "swapRead": 0,
            "swapWrite": 0
        }
    },
    "storeMemory": 393216,
    "storeMemoryLimit": 1073741824,
    "storeTotalUse": 1048576,
    "swapRead": 6,
    "swapReadSize": 393216,
    "swapReadTime": 7,
    "swapReadUncompressTime": 0,
    "swapWrite": 0,
    "swapWriteCompressTime": 0,
    "swapWriteSize": 0,
    "swapWriteTime": 0,
    "totalBackupLsn": 0,
    "totalLockConflictCount": 0,
    "totalOtherLsn": 0,
    "totalOwnerLsn": 72,
    "totalReadOperation": 0,
    "totalRowRead": 0,
    "totalRowWrite": 0,
    "totalWriteOperation": 0,
    "txnDetail": {
        "totalBackgroundOperation": 0
    }
},
"recovery": {
    "progressRate": 1
},
"version": "5.3.0-39942 CE"}
```